# I am using the cross value and dot product and combining them with the Atan2 function (I am using C# and unity) and it isn't working as intended

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

From my research I've come to the conclusion that this is a legitimate and fairly efficient and robust method for calculating angles, But it isn't working for me and I've been experimenting for a while now. And I understand I could've used the built in Cross and Dot functions that Unity offers, but I didn't so please don't take the time to comment, it's not helpful :)
Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 mousePos = (Vector2)Input.mousePosition;
        Vector2 playerDir = mousePos - (Vector2)player.transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(((mousePos.x * playerDir.y) - (mousePos.y * playerDir.x)), ((mousePos.x * playerDir.x) + (mousePos.y * playerDir.y))) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems here. First of all, `Input.mousePosition` gives you the mouse position on the screen, not the position in the world. To get the mouse position in the world you need to use your main camera to convert from screen space to world space, like this:

```cs
Camera mainCamera;

void Start() {
    mainCamera = Camera.main; // Camera.main is fairly expensive, so you shouldn't use it repeatedly
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector2 mousePos = (Vector2)mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    // ...
}
```

The second problem is that you don't need the cross or dot product for Atan2 at all. All you need is the relative position to another point and you'll get the angle to that point. In your case, you would simply write:

```cs
float angle = Mathf.Atan2(playerDir.y, playerDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
```

The final script should look something like this:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    
    Camera mainCamera;

    void Start() {
        mainCamera = Camera.main;
    }
    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 mousePos = (Vector2)mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector2 playerDir = mousePos - (Vector2)player.transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(playerDir.y, playerDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        player.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you! I tried this as well and it didn't work very well but I probably implemented it wrong, I'll try it again. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JustinDev I've added the final script (which I've tested and it works for me) to the post. Hope that helps.

Comment: If this answer is correct it would be helpful to others if you mark it as an accepted answer. It would also benefit the one who helped you by increasing their Reputation.